# PHP execution breaks without any notification

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing php code to
- retrieve files from my hard disk(d:/)
- make few calculations on the data of those files
- save the results into Database(MySQL).

Php is extracting file data,making required calculations and saving results to database.

My problem is my php automatically terminating after a certain amount of time(I don't know the time)

My first record creation(in database) time is 2014-09-10 14:29:57
My last record creation(in database) time is 2014-09-10 14:34:32.
When I run my php code again it is saving the remaining files.

Comment: did you check timeout? Read the error logs? Done any debugging? Have any code you want to share?

Comment: have you tried to consult php logs?

Comment: Try adding `set_time_limit(0)` at the beginning of your script

Comment: I dont know about timeout and please tell me how to check php logs

Comment: php default execution time 60s, change to unlimited to complete the execution

Comment: @Shafeeq as you can see the times i provided my php ran for almost 5 minutes,

Comment: Were you running this through a web server? Most web servers have a timeout, default for Apache is 5 minutes..... tasks that take that length of time to execute should generally be run as background tasks, or from the command line

Comment: @MarkBaker is there a way to extend that 5min. I am Using Apache

Comment: You can extend it in your apache configuration, it's the `Timeout` directive.... but not really recommended: like I said before, long-running tasks should be executed in the background, or as CLI processes

Comment: @ovi set_time_limit(0) is working. Thank you.

Comment: `set_time_limit(0)` is generally speaking a **bad idea**, unless you really know what you're doing. I'd recommend setting the time limit higher than default, but not "no-limit" (which 0 stands for in this case), because this can cause php process to hang for a long time for whatever reason.

Comment: @Kleskowy thank you for your advice, but my file list is random(which is unexpectable). Can you suggest me any other possible solution.

Comment: @user3616287 I'd do some tests to try to check the limit that is big enough to not interrupt your script prematurely and little enough not to be 0 ;) Setting it for `3600s` (1h) should be more than enough, and if it is not - you should thinkg about optimisation/refactoring of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put below line of code at top of your script

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the script from timing out, you need to increase the execution time of the specific processing script. Here's how you do it.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```